# Binding a variable over multiple quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I was having a discussion with some classmates about what the following means:

$$\exists x \forall x P(x)$$

As far as I understand, a variable can only be bound by one quantifier. I claimed that the innermost one should bind it, because that simply made most sense to me, but some argued that the existential should always bind it because it was the "weaker" of the two.

The way I see it, the $x$ is being quantified by the universal, so the existential is meaningless in this situation, so

$$\exists x \forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y \forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow  \forall x P(x)$$

It is similar to saying "there exists a number $x$ such that all numbers $x$ are equal to themselves", what this means is simply that all numbers are equal to themselves. The "exists a number $x$ such that" is unnecessary, because you're not doing anything with that number $x$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I would rather not use equality signs here. However. You are dealing here with a formula $\exists x Q$ where $Q$ does not have any free variables (so is a sentence). In that case the formulas $\exists x Q$  and $Q$ are *logically equivalent*.

Comment: @drhab thanks, i updated the Q

Comment: If you want to create confusion, then writing $\forall x \exists x \cdots$ would be good way to do it even if there is some obscure convention for making sense of it. As a matter of style, it is better to write,  $\forall x \exists y \cdots$.

Comment: @DanChristensen.  For all x, exists x with ...x... makes perfect sense.  For all x, exists y with ...x...y... is a different statement, a nonsequiter to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard convention is that the inner-most quantifier binds the variable. That is, you are correct in the sense that most logicians would read $\exists x \forall x P(x)$ as equivalent to $\exists y \forall x P(x)$.

However, this is really just convention. This choice happens to be relatively convenient, but it is ultimately not important. Another convention you could take is that $\exists x \forall x P(x)$ is not even a well-formed formula; you could postulate that if $\phi$ is a formula and $x$ is a variable, then $\exists x \phi$ and $\forall x \phi$ are only formulas if $x$ does not occur as a bound variable in $\phi$.

Comment: I can't agree with all you say here. To me to use the standard convention here is ultimately important because the standard convention here is much more right and elegant than any alternative I could think of. Foundations matter.

Comment: @StephenA.Meigs, I once worked in a context where this standard convention would have caused me a lot of headaches, so I adopted the convention described in the last sentence of this answer. If you think your perspective is missing you should add another answer, that's the nice thing about this platform (and I don't mean this in a hostile/sarcastic way).

Comment: It is by *definition* that a quantifier binds its variable, and when nested the inner most quantifier takes precedence. $~$ So $\exists x~\forall x~P(x)$ *is a well-formed formula* where the predicate's term is bound to the scope of the universal quantifier and thus inaccessible to the scope of the existential quantifier. $~$ However, yes, is not very *human-readable* to nest quantifiers in such a manner, and doing so should be discouraged to avert unnecessary confusion.